# How to manipulate tkinter GUI from an imported file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I try to create a small GUI with tkinter. To make my code more readable I want to split the code in 2 files. One for the GUI information and one for the process informations. Or is it a bad idea?

So I create a gui.py where I import my process informations from program.py.

gui.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from program import *

root = tk.Tk()

btn_Start = tk.Button(text="Start", command=start_loop)
btn_Stop  = tk.Button(text="Stop", command=stop_loop, state=tk.DISABLED)

btn_Start.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn_Stop.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

program.py:

```
def start_loop():
    print('disable Start button and enable Stop button')
    # what is the code to disable the start button and enable the stop button?
def stop_loop():
    print('disable Stop button and enable Start button')
    # what is the code to disable the stop button and enable the start button?
```

How do I tell the button the disable/enable information in my program.py file? I do not understand how I get the information from the gui to the program and back to the gui?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Simply pass the `btn_Start` and `btn_Stop` to `start_loop()` and `stop_loop()` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a small program, it is overkill.

Looking at the `tkinter` programs I've written, all of them are between 200−300 lines. This is *including* headers, comments and blank lines. The number of actual code lines is 100−200.
In my opinion that is small enough to comfortably handle in an editor in one file.

Looking over most of my source code repositories, the longest Python files tend to top out at around 230 lines of actual code.

Keeping all the code in one file has significant advantages for a program when you need to install it. Just copy the file and you're done. No need for modules and a `setup.py`.